# Start a program as NETWORK SERVICE user

Tags: permissions, windows-10, network-service, windows-users

I have a.exe and I'm a non-admin user in the windows 10 system. 
I want to run a.exe as NETWORK SERVICE user. I tried using PsExec but

```
C:\Users\Guest\Downloads\PSTools>psexec -i -u "nt authority\network service" a.exe

Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:
Access is denied.
```

Comment: You can't run psexec without being an administrative user.

Comment: Yeah understood. So is there any other way to launch a.exe as network service user ?